# SQL Server - Combining Bulk Insert with Manual value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a Comma separated CSV file containing ID, FirstName, and LastName. I am trying to insert it into my existing table, however the table has few more column which the CSV file is missing thus I am wondering if it's possible to insert the CSV file combined with manual value mapping ?

Below is how my table looks like:
[image]

And this is how my CSV file looks like:
[image]

As you can see, the CSV file only contains the `IdentityId` column of the Table (is's called `Id` in the file) and `Email` and other fields are missing, therefore I am wondering if I can manually provide them or I need to insert the bulk item first, and then write a command to update all of them?

Comment: Unclear. Show table structure, sample existing data (2-3 records), CSV text (2-3 records) and desured final table state. If some indices/constraints exists define what to do while violation.

Comment: @Akina, thank you, I have edited my question.

Comment: Please show: table structure **in `CREATE TABLE` form**; example data **and desured result** for that source data **in table form** with altered (not smeared) values.

Comment: You could import the existing CSV into a staging table that matches 1:1 with columns in the CSV file. Then you could update your main table from that making any required additions or modifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *possible* solution is to use [OPENROWSET](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openrowset-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Assuming a csv file (emp.txt):

```
User1,100,Dep1
User2,1000,Dep2
```

Assuming a format file (format_file.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <RECORD>
  <FIELD ID="1" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="20"/>
  <FIELD ID="2" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="," MAX_LENGTH="20"/>
  <FIELD ID="3" xsi:type="CharTerm" TERMINATOR="\r\n" MAX_LENGTH="20"/>
 </RECORD>
 <ROW>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="1" NAME="Name" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="2" NAME="Salary" xsi:type="SQLDECIMAL"/>
  <COLUMN SOURCE="3" NAME="DepartmentName" xsi:type="SQLNVARCHAR"/>
 </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

---

```
--demo setup
drop table if exists employees;
drop table if exists departments;
go
CREATE TABLE Employees (
    NAME NVARCHAR(20)
    ,Salary DECIMAL
    ,DepartmentID INT
    )
GO

CREATE TABLE Departments (
    DepartmentID INT
    ,DepartmentName NVARCHAR(20)
    )
GO

INSERT INTO Departments
VALUES (1,'Dep1')

INSERT INTO Departments
VALUES (2,'Dep2')

--solution
--Insert data into Employees table
INSERT INTO Employees
SELECT NAME
    ,Salary
    ,DepartmentID
FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'C:\testdata\emp.txt', FORMATFILE = 'C:\testdata\format_file.xml') emp
JOIN Departments dep ON (emp.DepartmentName = dep.DepartmentName)

--verify
select * from Employees
```

---

```
| NAME  | Salary | DepartmentID |
|-------|--------|--------------|
| User1 | 100    | 1            |
| User2 | 1000   | 2            |
```